# How can I make the cartesian product fo the members of a string or vector given a length?

Tags: c++11, brute-force, cartesian-product

I'm trying to make a program that gives me all the possible combinations of a vector or string members. I saw that it can be done with the std::cartesian_product function in C++, but all the examples I saw were between two lists. What I need is as follows:

If a have a vector like:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> letters = {"a", "b", "c", ..., "z"};
```

I want all the combiantions with different lengths. For example, if I want all the combiantions of minimum length 1 and maximum 2, it should be like:

```
a, b, c, d, ... , z, ab, ac, ad, ... , az, ... , zz
```

In Python, I did it using the itertools library, with the product function. I did it like this:

```py
for i in range(1, 3):
    for s in intertools.product(vector, repeat=i):
        print(''.join(s))
```

How should I do it? I'm a little bit lost with this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe one of these help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+cartesian+product

Comment: I think none of these works for me. In fact, I've already seen most of them